# Display filtered list in page layout

Tags: related-list, filters, custom-reports

I'm trying to display a list of records related to the record being viewed on its page layout. I could see doing this either by embedding a filtered list report or by creating a custom related list that's filtered.

My dataset looks like this: I have a single object that contains multiple records related records. For example:
- Name 1: Type A
- Name 2: Type A
- Name 3: Type A
- Name 4: Type B
- Name 5: Type B
- Name 6: Type C

So what I want is the embedded filtered list/filtered custom list to display the other related 'Types' on the page. So in the above example, viewing Name 1 would also show Name 2 and Name 3 somehow.

Is this possible?

Comment: I found  a  question on the salesforce forum that's similar, but I still can't seem to get it to work: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008pA9IAI  
The idea is to display related records from the same object on the page layout. This seems pretty basic - there must be a way for salesforce to accommodate this...?

Answer (score 0):

So I've got a reasonable workaround. What has to be done is:
1. First create a relationship (lookup or master-detail) between two objects
2. Create a Report Type that uses both objects
3. Create a report using the newly created report type
4. Include a filter in the report that you can group your items by. The non-ideal thing here is that the filter need to be typed in as a constant
5. Embed the report in the parent record

So in the above example, I have a lookup of the object "Names" to the object "Name Details" and created a report type that looked at both objects. I then created 3 reports, one for "Type A" one for "Type B" and one for "Type C" then embedded these reports into the page layout for the "Names" object.

This provided a 3 lists of related "Names" grouped by "Type". Hope this helps some for anyone else struggling with a similar setup.